# Regex finds multiple lines of string after a given string

Tags: regex

I have a paragraph below:

```
INSERT INTO `item` (`id`, `name`, `type`, `gender`, `level`, `icon`, `part`, `fashion`, `isUpToUp`) VALUES
(710, 'Black short', 6, 1, 1, 2656, 225, -1, 0),
(711, 'Assassin mask', 11, 1, 1, 2931, 223, -1, 0),
(712, 'Jirai shirt', 2, 1, 1, 2923, 224, -1, 0),

INSERT INTO `item_option` (`id`, `type`, `name`) VALUES
(0, 0, 'Attack in: +#'),
(1, 0, 'Attack out: +#'),
(2, 0, 'Fire res:  +#'),
```

How can I get all strings inside apostrophe, but after `INSERT INTO item_option (id, type, name) VALUES`?

I tried

```
(?<=INSERT INTO `item_option` \(`id`, `type`, `name`\) VALUES)(?<=').*(?=')
```

Sorry, I'm new at regex and above must be wrong

I just want:

```
Attack in: +#
Attack out: +#
Fire res:  +#
```

not

```
Black short
Assassin mask
Jirai shirt
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/hPNgyO/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thank you so much, that is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the regex engine you are using is PCRE compliant, you can use a pattern that follows this scheme:

```
(?:\G(?!^)<pattern_after_match_till_next_match>|<match_pattern_start>)<pattern_after_each_match_start>\K<what_you_need>
```

The pattern can look like

```
(?:\G(?!^)'\),|INSERT INTO `item_option` \(`id`, `type`, `name`\) VALUES)\R\(\d+,\s*\d+,\s*'\K[^']+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hPNgyO/1). *Details*:

- `` (?:\G(?!^)'\),|INSERT INTO `item_option` \(`id`, `type`, `name`\) VALUES) `` - either a `` INSERT INTO `item_option` (`id`, `type`, `name`) VALUES `` string or end of the previous match and a `'),` substring
- `\R` - a line break sequence
- `\(\d+,\s*\d+,\s*'` - `(` + one or more digits, `,`, zero or more whitespaces, one or more digits, `,`, zero or more whitespaces...
- `\K` - match reset operator, discards the text matched so far from the entire match memory buffer
- `[^']+` - one or more chars other than `'`

Comment: thank you so much, your explanation is very detail and clear!